# In Pandas to_csv function, i need to modify the seperator only for the header to ":"

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, csv

What is the best way to change ONLY the header separator to ":" while doing "to_csv" on a panda data frame?

For Example:

```
items = [['Phone', 2000, 'Apple'], ['TV', 1500, 'LG'], ['Radio', 800, 'FM'], ['Fridge',0,'LG']]  
df = pd.DataFrame(items, columns=['Item', 'Price', 'Model'], dtype=float)  
print(df) 


     Item   Price  Model
0   Phone  2000.0  Apple
1      TV  1500.0     LG
2   Radio   800.0     FM
3  Fridge     0.0     LG
```

When I convert this to CSV, i get

```
df.to_csv(index=False)
```

Output

```
'Item,Price,Model\nPhone,2000.0,Apple\nTV,1500.0,LG\nRadio,800.0,FM\nFridge,0.0,LG\n'
```

Instead i want the output as:

```
'Item:Price:Model\nPhone,2000.0,Apple\nTV,1500.0,LG\nRadio,800.0,FM\nFridge,0.0,LG\n'
```

Comment: may be `df.to_csv(sep=":", index=False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to support it, because the CSV writer underneath the hood treats the header like any other line.

The following snippet works but loses the atomicity of `to_csv`.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: items = [['Phone', 2000, 'Apple'], ['TV', 1500, 'LG'], ['Radio', 800, 'FM'], ['Fridge',0,'LG']]
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame(items, columns=['Item', 'Price', 'Model'], dtype=float)

In [3]: with open('out.csv', 'w') as f:
   ...:     f.write(':'.join(df.columns) + '\n')

In [4]: df.to_csv('out.csv', mode='a', header=False)

In [5]: !cat out.csv
Item:Price:Model
0,Phone,2000.0,Apple
1,TV,1500.0,LG
2,Radio,800.0,FM
3,Fridge,0.0,LG
```

Comment: Just a note, this solution opens and closes the file twice, which isn't strictly necessary. You can do everything within a single `with` statement.

Comment: Yep that's true, forgot `to_csv` supports that

Answer (score 1):

Different delimiters for headers versus data isn't supported by Pandas [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html). You can use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module from the standard library instead:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'w', newline='') as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter=':')  # define writer object for header output
    writer.writerow(df.columns)  # writerow accepts any iterable of strings or numbers
    df.to_csv(fout, header=False, index=False)  # comma delimiter is default
```

Result:

```
Item:Price:Model
Phone,2000.0,Apple
TV,1500.0,LG
Radio,800.0,FM
Fridge,0.0,LG
```